# parse groups of text

Tags: regex

Let's say I have a text file that looks like this:

```
group 1
group 1
 arbitrary text
group 1
 arbitrary text
group 2
 arbitrary text
 arbitrary text
group 2
group 2
 arbitrary text
#
```

I'd like to pull each group information keeping it together in it's own list then stop at '#'.

List1:

```
group 1
group 1
 arbitrary text
group 1
 arbitrary text
```

List2:

```
group 2
 arbitrary text
 arbitrary text
group 2
group 2
 arbitrary text
```

I've tried several things that didn't get anywhere close and my lambda skills are just about non-existent.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Several things such as...? And what language/tool?

Comment: Show us the "several things" that didn't work.  Tell us what your results were and what you were expecting.

Comment: So the group names always start in the first column whereas the arbitrary text parts are all indented by at least one space?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the head, using System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx class (.NET Framework), here is a simple pattern that almost do what you want:

`group\ (\d+)[\w\W]*group\ \1`

The problem is, it doesn't catch the last ' arbitrary text' before the next group starts, and lacks of checking the # char to stop the capture. But it is a good start I think :)

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"group\ (\d+)[\w\W]*group\ \1", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```